# problem when using javax.validation.Validator and others

Tags: java, gwt, bean-validation

I'm trying to validate something using the [GWT BeanValidation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/BeanValidation) but these two lines are giving me some trouble:

```
Validator validator=Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Contact>> violations = validator.validate(contact, Default.class);
```

The thing is, I have imported the corresponding classes:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.groups.Default;
```

But still, the Validator, Validation, ConstraingViolation and Default references in the code are underlined in red and the error they show is:

```
javax.validation.Validator can not be found in source packages. Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly.
```

I have checked that the necessary lib validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar is in the classpath and everything seems normal.

Anyone happens to know what could be the problem?

thanks!!

Comment: SpringSource Tool Suite (sorry I forgot to give that detail)

Comment: So, your IDE is Eclipse. Have you checked that the JAR file is present at the _Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries_ page?

Comment: yes, as I said above, I checked it. It's under the Maven Dependencies Library.

Answer (score 1):

I see only two possibilities

1. Check the size of jar file , either in your local maven repository which your build path is pointing to or check that in your eclipse by browsing its source code to double check its there :)
2. Have you inherited this is any awt module using ? Can you check its syntax or if it is really required?

Comment: yeah, the problem is that GWT doesn't let you use any class freely. First it has to be inherited via a module in the gwt.xml. 
In the end, I chose to work with another validation library: GWT-VL

Answer (score 0):

Do you have validator-implementation in your classpath? AFAIK, javax.validation is only the API (interfaces), you'll need an actual validator-implementation to use it. See for example [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Comment: he is using GWT Bean validation